# HTML encoding custom HTML helper

Tags: model-view-controller, helper, html-encode

I wish to encode my HTML sent to the browser.  In my .ASPX pages I can use the <%: %> syntax.  In a HTML helper of mine I try...

```
    public static string Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageName, string altText)
    {
        return helper.Encode(String.Format("<image src='/images/{0}' alt='{1}' />", imageName, altText));
    }
```

However, when the HTML reaches the browser the HTML just displays as text and no image is shown.  How does one encode their HTML from a helper method?

Comment: are you calling the helper on your page with <%: or <%= ?

Comment: I tried both.  Neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

remove the "helper.Encode"

```
public static String MyImg(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageName, string altText) {
   return String.Format("<image src='/images/{0}' alt='{1}' />", imageName, altText);
}
```

Comment: Yes, tried that.  So if I remove helper.Encode, but in the view use the <%: syntax to encode the string, I just get the printed HTML in the web page (vs. the image it is supposed to display).  Of course using <%= works just fine (but isn't encoded).

Comment: Yes "<%:" encode the string that is returned.
You have to use "<%=" sintax.